# backbone.js rendering view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is my view for Backbone

```
var RepoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#wrapper'),

  events: {
    "click #more_repos" : "get_more_repos"
  },

  get_more_repos: function() {
    ajax(get_repo_url, {offset:2}, this.render);
  },

  render: function(result) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#repos_hb").html());
    $(this.el).find('#main_content').append(template({repos: result}));
    return this;  
  }
});
```

And this is my ajax function that gets called from "get_more_repos" function

```
function ajax(url, data, post_ajax_function) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url, 
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
      post_ajax_function(result);
    }
  });    
}
```

However, it is not rendering, because "this.el" is undefined. Now after playing with it for awhile, it looks like the callback in "ajax(..)" function doesn't have access to "this.el". Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: the reason "this.el" was undefined was because I missed "_.bindAll(this, render)". Just like the manual says about the context.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the callback method is executed in the context of the ajax call, not in the context of your view. you need to use the `_.bindAll` method to correct this, in your view's initializer:

```
var RepoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#wrapper'),

  events: {
    "click #more_repos" : "get_more_repos"
  },

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
  },

  get_more_repos: function() {
    ajax(get_repo_url, {offset:2}, this.render);
  },

  render: function(result) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#repos_hb").html());
    $(this.el).find('#main_content').append(template({repos: result}));
    return this;  
  }
});
```

this will set up the `render` method to always execute in the context of the view, which will give you access to `this.el` even when used as a callback.

FYI - you may run into another issue related to `el`. if your view is defined before the DOM has finished loading, the jQuery call to `$("#wrapper")` will fail to find anything. to fix this, i typically put the jquery call in the view initializer, too.

```
initialize: function(){
  this.el = $("#wrapper");
  // ... other stuff here
}
```

there are other ways around this... but i wanted to include this note, just in case. :)

Comment: I ran into the same problem noted in your FYI and ended up using the same solution...Is there any chance the DOM won't be ready on initialize?

Comment: if you initialize the view before the DOM is ready, then yes :) see this blog post: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/ it should fill you in on more info related to this.

Comment: Fantastic...not the first of your articles I've read...thanks for blogging!

Answer (score 0):

At some point you have to call the render method.  You'll need some code like the following:

```
var view = new RepoListView();
view.render();
```

In fact I would modify it slightly to look like this, removing the el definition from your view:

```
var view = new RepoListView({
    el: $('#wrapper')
});
view.render();
```